# How to safely store sensitive data?

Tags: python, security, encryption, passwords

I'm currently writing a program sending data to a server using a private apikey.
I don't want to keep the key in plaintext, but i need it to contact the server.

What kind of reversible encryption could work for this ?

Comment: `chmod 600 apiKeyFile`?

Comment: I thought the point of an API key is that it's not a password so if it's lost or stolen the damage is very minor.

Comment: Why don't you want to keep the key in plaintext?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that if you give someone the program and it needs to use the API key, there is no way to avoid giving out the API key.  The best you can hope for is to obscure it enough that someone will think it is easier to get the API key elsewhere.  Supposing that the API key is so difficult to get elsewhere that someone persists in attempting to decode it from your program, they *will eventually get it*.

Consider that the end user will be able to snoop on communications with the server, even going man in the middle on an SSL connection, where you are almost certainly sending the key plain-text anyways.

Apply some nuisance crypto, like rot13, and forget about it.

Answer (score 2):

[pycrypto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto) has many tools for this.  They have many standard types of encryption included in the module.

[Here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/CheeseShopTutorial) is a quick tutorial.

Comment: SHA-2 isn't encryption, it's a hash and hence irreversible. And encryption does not necessarily help: If you just put `ENCRYPTED_API_KEY = ...; AES_KEY = ...; AES_OPTIONS = ...` in some file then it doesn't take a genius to just feed that to any AES implementations and retrieve the plaintext.